# Parsing IST abbreviation to +0530 in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, datetime-parsing

I am getting response from Java Backend Call which return date in format

`Wed Mar 20 09:17:11 IST 2019`

but in javascript , I need to parse the above date time format , using moment or any other library to this required Format
`Wed Mar 20 09:17:11+0530 2019`

I think it is not able to parse the abbreviation IST to +0530.

I need a parsing so that , I can convert the backend string to a Moment object

Comment: Can you get the backend format changed so it returns a standardized string? The solution to your problem would be very simple: `new Date( ... ).toLocaleString( ... )`, but only if new Date() can parse what the backend call returns. Hence we prefer having ISO 8601 format or unix timestamp, as both can directly be parsed into a valid Date object. Else you're stuck with splitting and manipulating the string yourself. Maybe moment.js has extra functions to parse such formats.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067769/3233827

Comment: Do educate that backend Java programmer. They are using the terrible `java.util.Date::toString` class and method. That class was supplanted  years ago by the `java.time.Instant` class, whose `toString` method emits text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Example: `Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).toString()`.

Comment: Tried this out 
```moment("Wed Mar 20 09:17:11 IST 2019","ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ? YYYY")
```
  but eventually got it changed from Java Backend , to ISO 8601 format