# How to convert dates with 3 letter timezone abbreviation, to UTC, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-format

I need to convert datetimes from an input format which I can't change (this: "Tue, 30 Jul 2019 21:15:53 GMT") to UTC, in Javascript.

I actually need to get these dates as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1970) but getting in UTC would be a start.

Is there a way to do this easily? I can use a 3rd party library if needed. I've heard of moment-timezone.js but not clear how to parse the 3 letter timezone, i.e. these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations.

Comment: You're going to have a problem as those three-letter combinations are not unique. See, for example, `ACT` and `AMT`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you want this as UNIX date or you want the results as UTC string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution is a library that maps these abbreviations to offsets from GMT. Neither [`moment-timezone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065620/momentjs-and-timezone-abbreviations), nor [`date-fns-tz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz), nor [luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/zones.md), nor [`timezone-support`](https://github.com/prantlf/timezone-support/issues/32) do this, but [timezone-abbr-offsets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-abbr-offsets) does and is [very minimalistic](https://github.com/jazzpi/timezone-abbr-offsets).

Fortunately, `new Date()` can parse your format minus the timezone, so we'll split that away and calculate the offset back:

```js
import timezones from 'timezone-abbr-offsets';

function abbrTzToUtc(dateString) {
  // Get the date and the timezone from the input string
  let [, date, tz] = dateString.match(/^(.*)\s+(\w+)$/);
  // Ignore the timezone and parse the date as GMT
  date = new Date(date + 'Z');
  // Add the offset caused by the original timezone
  date = new Date(date.getTime() + timezones[tz] * 60 * 1000);
  return date;
}

console.log(abbrTzToUtc('Tue, 30 Jul 2019 21:15:53 MET'));
```

As a test, the code above should return `2019-07-30T22:15:53.000Z`.

If you want number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, `return date.getTime()` instead.

Comment: should be `-`, not `+ timezones[...`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert the date into UTC format you can use toISOString()

```
new Date('Tue, 30 Jul 2019 21:15:53 GMT').toISOString()
```

For more info please check this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Moreover, to convert the date into milliseconds you can use Date.UTC()

```
Date.UTC(year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]])
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Example:

```
utcMillisecond = (e) => {
    const regex = /(T)|(:)|(-)/g;
    const utc = new Date(e).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(regex, ' ').split(' ');
    const utcMillisecond = Date.UTC(utc[0], utc[1], utc[2], utc[3], utc[4])
    return utcMillisecond
}

utcMillisecond("Tue, 30 Jul 2019 21:15:53 GMT")
//1567199700000
```

Comment: This will work for *some* timezones, e.g. `new Date('1/1/2020 EST')`, but not others, even unique ones: `new Date('1/1/2020 MET')`. This might depend on what locales are available in the runtime, but that MET example doesn't work on my US English system.